# Execute a Javascript function when Validation fires in DevExprerss

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am using Dev express Controls. 
 
I have some ASPxTextboxes on my webpage, and i have added ASPxValidationSummary. How can i know when validation summary fires?  i mean i want to apply some css stylesheet to my Textboxes when they are not valid. Also is it possible to display validationImage and summary both?

Thanks.